# Simple way to shorten time period of graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, quantmod

Let's consider data :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
start <- as.Date("2013-01-01")
end <- as.Date("2016-10-01")
# Apple stock
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)
```

And plot :

```
autoplot(Cl(AAPL))
```

[image]

My question is : is there any way how can I simlpy shorten time period of my plot ? Let's say for example I want to have my plot from '2013-01-01' up to '2014-01-01'. Of course I can do exactly same thing with changing my `start` and `end` variables (defined at the very beggining) and redownload data set. However I found this solution inefficient. Is there any simpler way how it can be performed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches. One is to specify limits to the plotting routine and the other is to subset the data itself.  Since the first one is already illustrated by another answer we will focus on the second:

```
# xts suppports .../... notation
apple <- Cl(AAPL)['2013-01-01/2014-01-01']

# this will extract all rows for 2013
apple <- Cl(AAPL)['2013']

# window function
apple <- window(Cl(AAPL), start = "2013-01-01", end = "2014-01-01")
```

Having defined `apple` we can `autoplot` it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `xlim =`  argument to `autoplot`:

```
autoplot(Cl(AAPL),
         xlim = as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2016-04-01")))
```

[image]

You can also use the `+` operator if you prefer:

```
autoplot(Cl(AAPL)) +
  xlim(as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2016-04-01")))
```

See `help(autoplot.zoo)` for more.